# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element / WebSphere-Liberty Migration from WebSphere-7

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, websphere-liberty, websphere-7

The code that is working in WebSphere-7 is giving the following error in WebSphere Liberty:

```
        javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unexpected element {http://example.com/service/Quoting/v2}SubmitRateScenarioResponse found.
       Expected {http://example.com/esb/header/v3}ESBHeader.
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)

        Caused by: 
        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected element {http://example.com/service/Quoting/v2}SubmitRateScenarioResponse found.   
Expected {http://example.com/esb/header/v3}ESBHeader.
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.validatePart(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:275)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please attach your server.xml file. Are you enabling jax-ws support in Liberty? As Liberty is using CXF also for JAX-WS and it may conflict with the Libs you are bundling with the app.

Comment: Hi Thanks for helping... 
I have enabled <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature> and also in the pom I have AXIS dependency 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
 <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
 <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>axis</groupId>
 <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
 <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>......
Do you think these ones causing the issue ?

Comment: This issue is resolved. The WSDL has <Header> part under response message and the Liberty the JAX-WS is strictly looking for it. After removing the part from WSDL the issue is gone in LIBERTY environment.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem seems to be that the SOAP Message received by the Service contains unexpected content. The client is building a SOAP Message that is violating the contract between the Service and Client. Sorry, I can't give you a better answer without more information.

Understanding what the Service is expecting compared to what the client is sending is key, and finding that would be possible with some more work. To start, I would compare what the Soap Message looks like when sent by the client on v7 to what the client is sending on Liberty by using a tool like tcpmon or fiddler to capture the message.

Were both the client and service migrated to Liberty from WebSphere V7? If you migrated the Service, was it migrated as a binary or rebuilt from a WSDL? If it was rebuilt, comparing the original WSDL from v7 to the rebuilt WSDL might tell you something about how the Service's expectations have changed.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Only the Client is migrating to Liberty. And service is Data Power and Sales Force. We connect to Sales Force through Data Power. Able to send Outbound Message and getting the response. When processing the response getting the Fault Exception.

Comment: The WSDL is not changed at the Service(Data power and Sales force) side. Same WSDL using in the Liberty.

Comment: The Request Message (Outbound Message) is similar in both Liberty and Webpshere-7 expect the tag names. In WAS_7 the tag is <soap:Envelope> and WAS-Liberty is <soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: This issue is resolved. The WSDL has <Header> part under response message and the Liberty the JAX-WS is strictly looking for it. After removing the part from WSDL the issue is gone in LIBERTY environment.

Answer (score 0):

Go through below url . may be you will find your solution

i was getting same error when i tried to hit rest api using postman client .

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/i-am-getting-exception-org-apache-cxf-interceptor-Fault-org-apache-camel-CamelContext-td5742012.html#a5742016

Root cause is - camel-core jar is missed . put jar file on server->lib or apache/lib

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you read comment below OP, the issue is resolved for OP on 2nd Nov, 2018, though it is good to post as an answer if you are certain that issue will be solved by your approach, which is not the case.